# How to make IntelliJ treat a file by its extension instead of as a text file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I mis-clicked something, and now user.tag is treated as a textfile instead of as a tag file. I tried deleting it and recreating it, but that didn't help - the file is still shown without any syntax highlighting.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see **File | Settings | File Types**.